# Creating a "User edit path" menu

Tags: 7, users

I want to create a menu with title "Edit" and path "user edit path". I tried to put user/%user/edit; user/%id/edit but no success. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 9):

You can use user/[current-user:uid]/edit once you have the [menu_token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) module installed.

Comment: Perhaps mark this as answered. :-)

Comment: This should be useful - [ask]

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the [Me Aliases](http://drupal.org/project/me) module. It provides shortcut paths to current user's pages, eg user/me, blog/me, user/me/edit, tracker/me etc.

This means you can use 'me' in your menu path.

Answer (score 1):

Programatically a link to current logged in user's edit page can be created like this (in a custom module or in user template page):

```
    <?php
    if (user_is_logged_in()) {
        global $user;?>
        <a href="<?php print $user->uid . '/edit/'; ?> " >Edit</a>
    <?php } ?>
```